# My HDD doesn't show on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

**Environment**
OS : Ubuntu 20.04 in SSD (I also tested Ubuntu 22.04)
Hard Disk : Western Digital Hard Disk 10TB (model : WUS721010ALE6L4)

**Problem**
When I have connected a Hard Disk to a PC, Bios(UEFI) well recognizes it.
The model number of the hard disk is correctly displayed on the Bios screen.

But the HDD isn’t shown by the `sudo fdisk -l` command in terminal. Also, Disk utility application does not show the HDD, so that i cannot format it.

When I enter `lspci -k | grep SATA`, I get the following results.

***The OS has a correct driver or controller for the HDD?***

```
--results--\
SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)\
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]\
```

(And these upper two lines are repeated 4 times……)

Comment: How about terminal command  `df -h`? Can you see the drive? And by Disk utility application, you mean Disks?

Comment: @user3169 Let me check ```df -h```. Yes, disk utility application means Disks.

Comment: `lsblk`? `dmesg`?